Minimize RAM usage of pandas operations in python
I have a python function using pandas that does operations on some dataframes. This python functions currently consumes a lot of RAM. I have tried to minimize RAM usage as much as possible but currently I've not been successfull.
My data is ~1.5 Go in memory (all dataframes summed), but the peak RAM usage of the python process running this function is ~15 Go.
Here is the current code of the function (df1, df2, df3, df4 are my function's inputs):
return (
        df1
        .query("`col1` == 'val1'")
        .merge(
            right=(
                df2
            ),
            on=["col2"],
            how="left",
        ).merge(
            right=(
                df3
            ),
            on=["col3"],
            how="left"
        ).merge(
            right=(
                df4
            ),
            on=["col4"],
            how='left',
        )
        .sort_values(
            by=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
            ascending=False
        )
        .drop_duplicates(["col2", "col3"])
    )

I have already tried the following:

Reduce memory footprint by setting optimal types to my pandas dataframes
Reduce memory footprint by filtering out non necessary columns

Any further idea on what could be optimized ? What am I doing wrong ?

Is there an opportunity to drop duplicates before joining to reduce the amount of data involved in these multiple merge steps?

Dropping duplicates first is a good idea. Thank you

The dataframe indeed contained a lot of duplicated data. Deduplicating earlier solved my problem. Thank you very much !
